# Location search parameters disappear when I load a new template

Tags: angularjs

I am using `$location.search(params)` to store an array in my url.  This array has determines how the page will load.  It works well only problem is that I have a set of tabs on my page, when ever I click the the tab a new template is loaded with a new controller and the url variables disappear.

I dont understand this behavior `$location.search()` is not being called again in the new controller.  How can I get the Url to stay static?

Answer (score 0):

In the $routeProvider set `reloadOnSearch: false` so you don't reload when $location.search() changes.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment but I dont believe that is what I am after.  The problem is not when I change $location.search().  The problem is when I click one of the the buttons (tabs) that cause a template to change.  This template also has a new controller that is loaded.  I believe that this process causes the variables in the URL (set by $location.search()) to clear.

Comment: Try creating a factory to store your variables at a more global level.

Answer (score 0):

Change the path using

```
$location.path('/differentRoute').search(params);
```

Doing so would change the route and set the search parameters again.

Comment: That did not work.  It still disappears as described above.

Comment: @user2121775 Edited the code. Can you try this out?